# Get name of USB device in linux using usb4java

Tags: java, linux, usb-drive, usb4java

I want to get the name of the USB disk with its path in Linux eg. "/media/Disk_data".Following is my method

```
    private static void dumpDevice(Device device) throws LibUsbException {

        final int address = LibUsb.getDeviceAddress(device);
        final int busNumber = LibUsb.getBusNumber(device);

        System.out.println(String.format("Device %03d/%03d", busNumber, address));

        DeviceDescriptor deviceDescriptor = new DeviceDescriptor();
        LibUsb.getDeviceDescriptor(device, deviceDescriptor);

        for (byte i = 0; i < deviceDescriptor.bNumConfigurations(); i += 1)
        {
            final ConfigDescriptor descriptor = new ConfigDescriptor();
            final int result = LibUsb.getConfigDescriptor(device, i, descriptor);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                throw new LibUsbException(" abc Unable to read config descriptor",
                    result);
            }
            try
            {
                if(descriptor.dump().contains("Mass Storage")){
                    System.out.println("\nConfigDescriptor.dump() -> "+descriptor.dump());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure that the config descriptor is freed
                LibUsb.freeConfigDescriptor(descriptor);
            }
        }
}
```

I am using usb4java-1.2.0.jar.
It gives me all the information about the configuration of "Disk_data" usb drive.But i am not getting its path.how do I get the name and whole path of this specific disk using this lib?

Comment: try this `http://quandtum.weebly.com/2/post/2012/08/getting-the-details-of-a-usb-device.html`

Comment: "/media/Disk_data" is a mount point, not a device file like "/dev/sdb". libusb won't give you any of them. You'll need to look at `udev` instead, unfortunately there are no easy way to get this from java.